# Loosing session variables in page to page redirection. When i am enabling javascript debugging with break point in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging, session, visual-studio-2019

Before when i run my asp.net project in Visual studio 2019 with out enabling the javascript everything was working fine. But when i added a break point in javascript in one of the JS file. Visual studio told me to click OK to enable javascript debugging. (I exactly dont remember what that pop up message was but it was something related to enabling the JS debugger.) After this modification in visual studio i am finding issue in getting session value from one page to other. I am looking for a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi sir, i tried this but issue seems same when i add the line which you said cookieless="true" in web config. I am not able to login in the first page only. The button not working. So i thought will work on this issue in a bit of time as we encountered some major issues in client application which is on production run. So clearing those major issues and planning to work on this issue may be in weekend.

Comment: ok will try this..

Answer (score 0):

> Loosing session variables in visual studio 2019 when i am enabling
>   javascript debugging with break point

Please try these steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)**  please add  `cookieless="true"` in `web.config` file like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages enableSessionState="true">
    <sessionState 
      cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**2)** disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` in case some extensions conflict with `enable javascript debugging` option.

**3)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder and then restart our project.

**In addition**, you can also uncheck `Enable Javascript debugging` option under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General` and debug javascript in the traditional way in Google browser. And you can just set a breakpoint in the Google browser.

[image]

Before it, you should install Google and then set it as web browser in VS2019. You can check [this link](https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome) to debug it.